# Rails / ActiveRecord: How to quote protected column name using #select in custom query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Running Rails 4.0.13 with TinyTDS connected to Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I'm trying to run the following query:

```
sql = Model.where(:foo => bar).select(:open, :high, :low, :close).to_sql
Model.connection.execute(sql)
```

The problem is, the generated sql is

```
"SELECT open, high, low, close FROM [models]"
```

Which gives me an error as the column names open and close are protected.

```
TinyTds::Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'open'
```

If I use `#pluck`, I can see the correct SQL is generated (with column names escaped):

```
"SELECT [models].[open], [models].[high], [models].[low], [models].[close] FROM [models]"
```

However, this produces an array, which is not what I want.

My question is how can i get `#select` to correctly quote the column names?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can make the select method to protect your column names when using symbols (maybe because different DBMS use different quoting identifiers), but you could pass your selection as a string :

```
sql = Model.where(:foo => bar).select("[open], [high], [low], [close]").to_sql
Model.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to submit a bug report to Rails, however in doing so I saw the problem did not appear to exists using SQLite test case, this leads me to believe the issue is with the SQL Server Adapter.

Since I am on Rails 4 and not the latest version of the adapter I left it and wrote the following (horrible) method as wrapping the column names was not enough, I needed to prefix the table to prevent ambiguous column names. Yuck

```
  def self.quote(*columns, klass)
    columns.map { |col| "[#{klass.table_name}].[#{col}]" }.join(', ')
  end
```

Comment: that's probably because your column names are not reserved words in SQLite but they are in SQL Server. 
Be careful, your quoting method won't work with every DBMS ! I think the SQL standard for quoting column names is " (double quotes)